# Parsley Validation

Tags: parsley.js

I'm using parlsey validation and all is good. The problem is that if you partially load the website or load the website and click on "send" before everything is loaded, then parsley validation does not work.

Its not working because it hasn't been loaded. However, the validation script for parsley is in the header of the document? Is there a way to load a script before the website is loaded at all?

Answer (score 3):

No that's not possible. If you place the JavaScript src in the head of the HTML document that's moste likely the only thing you can do. But that's not a good idea at all. JavaScript has to be placed before the closing body tag - at least until all Browsers and Servers are using SPDY.

The problem you are facing is caused by the way parsley works. While loading the page it will "scan" the HTML markup and search for parsley validation informations and apply bindings to them. It seems that this is not fully done.

What you can do is trying to avoid hitting a submit or what you use for submitting a form before the [domready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event is available. You could eg. set a submitt button for the form to disabled ...

Comment: Thank you. :) How could i disable the form submit button until everything is loaded? We've been receiving completely blank forms even when values are set on certain field inputs. How could someone send the form through completely blank??

Comment: load the page -> find the submitt button -> set preventDefault() via JavaScript for the button -> when your form is validated -> fire the submit event by hand with yoursubmitbutton.submit(). The form can be sent with blank values when the user deactivated JavaScript in the browser and you do not validate the form on the server side. The JavaScript validation is just a convenience but you should always validate the values on the server side :)